# Android: parsing JSON date

Tags: android, json, parsing, datetime

I'm getting from the server a Json object with this format `"Date": "/Date(1337032800000+0000)/"` and I need it to be like "1 April".

I'm trying to parse it like this, but I always get a `"Unparseable date" message`:

```
mDate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Date");
                    String shortDate = mDate.substring(6, mDate.length()-7);
                    String format="yyyy-MM-dd";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
                    try {
                        Date date = sdf.parse(shortDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to modify your original response something like replace */Date/*

```
String data = "/Date(1337032800000+0000)/";
String result = data.replaceAll("^/Date\\(" , "");
result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf('+'));
```

now you have `1337032800000` which is date in Millisecond.

Comment: with this, it just trims the part at the beginning, not in the end

Answer (score 2):

This is timestamp? Why you just don't change String to long and:

```
Date date = new Date();
date.setTime(yourLongVariable);
```

Month:

```
    int month = date.getMonth();

    months = " " + res.getString(R.string.january);
    if(month == 2)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.febuary);
    }
    else if(month == 3)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.march);
    }
    else if(month == 4)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.april);
    }
    else if(month == 5)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.may);
    }
    else if(month == 6)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.june);
    }
    else if(month == 7)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.july);
    }
    else if(month == 8)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.august);
    }
    else if(month == 9)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.september);
    }
    else if(month == 10)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.october);
    }
    else if(month == 11)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.november);
    }
    else if(month == 12)
    {
        months = " " + res.getString(R.string.december);
    }
```

I know that this is not pro, but it works for me.

Comment: this works, but how can I customize the format of the date to show? I just need "1 april"

Comment: better, but still the time for example, which I don't need =)

Comment: in one of my app when I wanted to get exactly date format as I wanted to I was getting the date.getDate() and for months I was date.getMonth() and check was number added right month string.

Comment: Use android `DateFormat` to format your date. `DateFormat.Format("dd MMMM",date);` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMMMMMMM"); and we will have the name of the month